# What term can be given to the line "Go to development hell"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

In the sentence, "*Battleship* sank at the box office, earning just a third of its $200-million-plus budget, and the ripple effect was swift: *Monopoly* went directly past Go to development hell, and Universal shed its much-hyped Hasbro partnership, paying millions in penalties to not make movies" is there a name/term or phrase which can be given to the "Go to development hell" phrase?

Comment: The phrase isn't really 'Go to development hell', 'Go' is what *Monopoly* went 'directly past' and 'Development Hell' is where it went. The whole being a reference to the *Monopoly* board game 'Chance' card directing the recipient to 'Go to Jail. Go directly to Jail, do not pass 'Go', do not collect £200.'

Comment: It's an ironic play on words, as explained well by Spagirl, that give the Monopoly creators a taste of their own medicine.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I made a mistake though. It's a Community Chest card!

Comment: @Spagirl - Shocked, shocked I tell you. You go directly to crash on the stack exchange!

Comment: I assume "Battleship" is in part a reference to [the Monopoly token](http://money.cnn.com/2017/03/17/technology/monopoly-classic-game-tokens/). Taking it all in context, I'd say *to go directly past Go to development hell* is essentially a somewhat ***overstretched metaphor***.

Comment: Actually, in this context both Battleship and Monopoly are films.  This sentence was taken out of a WJEC English Language AS/A Level past paper.  Here's a link if you want to see: http://pastpapers.download.wjec.co.uk/s15-1151-01.pdf (section B)

Comment: I was going to suggest "boondoggle" but my understanding of the word seems different than the dictionary definitions.  A "fiasco" also comes to mind. I might write up fiasco

Comment: from a comment to a response I made the OP may be looking for what to call that sort of expression .. and I think it would be a colloquialism but perhaps an idiom would be more correct for those that thought there was some derivation from the Monopoly phrase.. here is someones blog entry on the two words http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/03/idiomatic-colloquial.html

Answer (score 2):

The clue to understanding this phrase is that the sentence is about *Monopoly*, the film of [the board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_(game)) and the sentence alludes to parts of the game which have passed into common parlance.

A feature of the Board game are squares on the board which advance or retard the player's fortunes. 
 the **GO** square is where players begin their circuits of the board and is the point at which they are paid £/$200 each time they complete a circuit.
 **JAIL** lies in the opposite corner of the board and players are sent there by landing on the **GO TO JAIL** square or by turning up the **Community Chest** or **Chance** *GO TO JAIL* card[image][image]
Players must roll a double, deploy a 'Get out of Jail Free Card or pay a fine before they can take full part in the game again.
[image]
Therefore the phrase isn't really 'Go to development hell', 'Go' is what *Monopoly* went 'directly past' and 'Development Hell' is where it went.

Comment: To add to the information provided by Spagirl, and to answer (a slightly modified version of) the original question, the phrase "*Monopoly* went directly past Go to development hell" is an **allusion** to the game of *Monopoly*.